# Showing that this IVP has a solution for all of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm preparing for an exam and came across this problem:

Given the IVP

> > $f'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1+x^2+(f(x))^2}$
> >
> > $f(x_0) = y_0$

-show this has an unique solution $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

-What is the solution if $y_0=0$?

We're using the Picard-Lindelof Theorem, so we need to show Lipschitz of $F(x,y)$ where $f'(x)=F(x,y)$ in y on the region on which the IVP is defined.  Clearly $F(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so I assume we'll just have to show Lipschitz and we're done. This is where I run into a snag, however - how do I show $|F(x,y)-F(x,y_1)| \leq C|y-y_1|$?

Comment: So I got this far: $|F(x,y) - F(x,y_1)| = \left|\frac{y}{1+x^2+y^2}-\frac{y_1}{1+x^2+y_1^2}\right| = \left|\frac{(1+x^2-yy_1)(y-y_1)}{(1+x^2+y^2)(1+x^2+y_1^2)}\right| =\left|\frac{1+x^2-yy_1}{(1+x^2+y^2)(1+x^2+y_1^2)}\right||y-y_1|$ Not sure if this helps. But I guess now you just have to figure out what value the coefficient is bounded by.

Comment: Alright, thanks - I wasn't sure if I should've bothered combining the two expressions.  I'll see what comes of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
\left|\frac{y}{1+x^2+y^2}-\frac{y_1}{1+x^2+y_1^2}\right|
\leq
\left|\frac{y}{1+x^2+y^2}-\frac{y_1}{1+x^2+y^2}\right|
+\left|\frac{y_1}{1+x^2+y^2}-\frac{y_1}{1+x^2+y_1^2}\right|\\
=\frac{|y-y_1|}{1+x^2+y^2}+\left|\frac{|y_1|(1+x^2+y_1^2)-|y_1|(1+x^2+y^2)}{(1+x^2+y^2)(1+x^2+y_1^2)}\right|\\
=\frac{|y-y_1|}{1+x^2+y^2}+\frac{|y_1||y_1^2-y^2|}{(1+x^2+y^2)(1+x^2+y_1^2)}\\
=\frac{|y-y_1|}{1+x^2+y^2}+\frac{|y_1||y_1+y|\,|y_1-y|}{(1+x^2+y^2)(1+x^2+y_1^2)}\\
\leq|y-y_1|+|y-y_1|\,\frac{(y_1^2+|y|)}{(1+y_1^2)(1+y^2)}\\
\leq2|y_1-y|
$$

Comment: Wow!  That was amazing!

Comment: Very good indeed - I can only dream of being able to pull this off during an exam, but it's good to see that it's possible to pull out the inequality directly.

Comment: Thanks. I often tell my students that "you have to believe" and keep pushing through the calculation. Of course, one needs to have an idea of what is the desired outcome. Here, the idea is that both denominators should be similar when $y_1$ and $y$ are close, so they shouldn't bother too much.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mean value theorem, and see that what you want to show is equivalent to showing
$$ \left| \frac{\partial}{\partial y} F(x,y) \right| \le C $$

Comment: Alright, thanks - I think I got it. I (hopefully correctly) showed that $\left| \frac{\partial}{\partial y} F(x,y) \right| \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}$ and this is clearly bounded.

Comment: I get $\frac1{1+x^2+y^2} + \frac{2y^2}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}$ as the bound.  I know in the actual derivative that the second term comes with a minus sign, but since we are taking absolute values, you need to be worried in case the second term is larger than the first.

Comment: But then maybe you argued that $\frac{y^2}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2} \le \frac1{1+x^2+y^2}$.  That would work.  But I just want to check that you did it properly.

Comment: Since we are merely trying to see if something is bounded, we don't need to get exact upper bounds.

Comment: I got $\frac1{1+x^2+y^2} - \frac{2y^2}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}$.  If we combine these two expressions, we get $\frac{1+x^2-y^2}{1+x^2+y^2}$ and then apply the triangle inequality.
There's a reason why I left calculus behind me...
However, it does seem like this is the way to go as it doesn't seem as straightforward to work with $F(x,y)-F(x,y_1)$ directly as per andraiamatrix's comment above.

Comment: $\frac{1+x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}$.

Comment: Right, yes. The denominator must be positive so we won't have to worry about that, hence the triangle inequality can be applied to the denominator. Then we can cancel out $1+x^2+y^2$ to get my result above.

Comment: Right.  But it is worth noting that the much cruder bound I wrote would have been sufficient.  And showing the cruder bound could save you effort in the long run.

Comment: Alright, thanks - it'll be worth it on exams.